# Google Sign Out iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I was trying to implement social login `(Google)` in my new application. For that I followed this link: [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating](http://Google%20Sign%20In)  and successfully able to add google login and fetched user basic information. But I got stuck in Sign Out Process. For logout I've written following line, But still users data doesn't remove. As when I tried to login again it pick last gmail id.

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
```

I tried to find out the solution for this. But no luck. If some one has experienced about this, please share. Or Is there any other way for google login and logout.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a same issue and not find any solution yet.

Comment: Means you are just sign out and it will not ask you for new authorization right..

Comment: Yeah @ashmi123 . It is not asking for new authorization second time.

Comment: please try with real device this problem occurs in simulator

Comment: @Birendra I am already debugging in real device.

Comment: try this one [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];

Comment: Are you taking custom button? If Yes than can you please try with GIDSignInButton once.

Comment: @NileshJha I had tried with GIDSignInButton

Comment: Any luck with this issue ?

Comment: @manonthemoon I think there is no code for sign out. So we need to sign out manually.

Answer (score -2):

You can manually sign Out from that page as below .

[image]