# Google sign out in

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, google-signin

I've implemented the Google SignIn code with authentication to access Google Drive and have a sign out button with the following recommended code from Google:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

However, every time after the first time I run the app, the signIn process no longer asks me for my password.

If I sign in and then press the my sign out button, the next time I press the sign in button I am prompted for a google account and then prompted to allow access to Google drive.

If I sign in and then quit the app without pressing the sign out button, the next time I press the sign in button I receive no prompts and am logged in completely.

This behavior appears to be consistent with Google's statement regarding their quick start code ([https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift/%22Google%20Quick%20Start%22)):
"Authorization information is stored in your Keychain, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization."

That is the GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut() sign out command appears to work on Google's end (have to pick a Google account and allow Google drive access on the next login), but not on the iOS end as it appears that iOS has saved the password (presumably in the keychain) and always gives it to Google when I sign in after the first time.

I saw the post for [Google Sign Out iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870426/google-sign-out-ios) where Birendra had recommended trying

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];
```

to remove the password from the iOS Device's keychain.

I have not had any luck finding out how to use that suggestion. Can someone explain how to remove the password information that the user entered using Google SignIn? (Assuming this is what needs to be done to completely log out the user). I'm using Swift.

Normally having the keychain remember the password for Google wouldn't be a problem, but this is an app to collect research data. The subjects will be using their own iOS device (iPhone) and log into the lab's Google account, so we don't want that password to stay in their keychain.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this post, you can use the following:

**Swift 5**

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()
```

> Disconnects the current user from the app and revokes previous
>   authentication. If the operation succeeds, the OAuth 2.0 token is also
>   removed from keychain.